# Form input id, name creation and bootstrap components

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This is the most complex form I have created thus far and I'm having troubles 1) figuring how to name all the `id` and `name` attributes and 2) figuring out if this is the best way to input the data (if all the groups are selected the modal gets pretty big).

Ultimately I will post all the data to another php script which will update a database.

The parent relationship of the form is the 'Activity' which can apply to multiple sub-groups. Once a sub-group is selected I need to collect specifics for the activity as it relates to the specific sub-group.

Upon submitting I will update the database with the values. The table below shows if someone would have entered 'Test1' as the activity name, checked the Group 1 & Group 2 check boxes and filled in the specific group information.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Activity Name      |  Group   |  CR   |   Start Date   |   End Date    |     Assignee     |    Notes      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        Test1           |    1     |  123  |   01/22/2015   |  01/23/2015   | email@email.com  |These are notes|
|        Test1           |    2     |  456  |   01/24/2015   |  01/25/2015   | email2@email.com  |These are notes|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have created a JSFiddle that shows the how the form will perform: http://jsfiddle.net/kqft2fxj/9/

Are my the `id` and `name` attributes correct or am I thinking about the sub-groups incorrectly?

Should I think about using bootstrap tabs or some other component instead of the hidden `div`'s? If you select all 6 groups it just makes the modal so long.

Thanks!

Comment: Since user can only focus on one entry at a time is it necessary to display more than one event? If not could use single set of inputs and reset after ajax success

Comment: @charlietfl I see what your saying. So do more of a wizard where the user would input the activity name and select the groups it applies to. Then leads the user through a wizard where they can input the group fields?

Comment: or just keep it the way it is (with single entry). At submit for each one, send data to server (ajax) then in success confirmation of submit  reset and roll up the form until they check another checkbox